# What's the name of this stand look thing mounted on bike's handle?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What's the name of this stand look thing mounted on bike's handle?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that a holder for a cell phone?

Comment: @Rattler No, not near to it.

Comment: So what does it do? Humor me...

Comment: It's a [Universal rotating clip mount for cell phones](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Universal-Rotating-Clip-Mount-Cell-Phone_60505748698.html) Follow the link...the photos are  almost identical.

Comment: Yeah, it's a mount for a cellphone or some other electronic device.  Several names.